# As a trustee and executor of a trust, can I "settle" the financial portion of a trust on my own?

Tags: united-states, taxes, trusts

regarding settling the trust as an executor: I have gone through the legal aspects of informing heirs regarding the trust, and assuming that there are only liquid assets, can I just make out checks to heirs and will I be able to do the rest with a program like turbo tax? I guess I'm looking to know if I can do it myself in terms of the financial aspects. I have an attorney but am concerned about the financial part, i.e., distributions. Is there any formal documentation or format to follow?

If the answer is no, what should I look for in terms of getting help?

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The settling of a trust is done by an executor (called a personal representative in some states) or as trustee, depending upon how the decedent held the property.  If you have been granted the power by the trust to do so and all of the numerous  legal requirements for settling the trust have been met then you can distribute the assets (I have done it).